# How to make objects from intersecting lines in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two curved lines and lines inbetween connecting them, but pathfinder divide randomly makes objects containing 4,1, or 2 boxes. How do I make each box a single object? [image: boxes ungroupable]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the shape builder tool. It should break apart the grouped boxes into single objects.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Pathfinder > Divide is not making shapes that "randomly" contain different amounts of boxes, the problem is the paths aren't completely intersecting.

A quick trick that may work is: Select your big spiral shape, go to effects > path > offset path. Enter a very small, negative value, like -.5 pt and hit OK. With the object still selected, go to Object > Expand Appearance. (You'll probably have to ungroup this object - right click > ungroup) Now your spiral shape is slightly constricted. Select your spiral and the intersecting lines and do Pathfinder > Divide. Hopefully, you had better luck this time. If not, undo all the steps, and try entering a greater negative value in the amount that you are offsetting the path with.

Comment: Using shapebuilder can give better hinta as to what is the problem.